# How do the LIGO facilities know that their gravitational waves have not been distorted by other events and other waves?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, gravitational-waves, interference

Several black hole collisions have been detected. How do they determine if the gravitational waves have been strengthened or weakened by interaction with other event waves?

Comment: Dark Matter, Dark Energy and all of the Galaxies in between means where was the collision?

Comment: 2 sets of detectors detected the same event at the same point in time. Coincidence?

Comment: The papers are here: http://www.ligo.caltech.edu/page/detection-companion-papers. For a specific observation, see for example: https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.116.241103. If you doubt their methodology, please be more explicit in your question.

Comment: Cloud you clarify your question? Are you asking about the possible complications of overlapping gravitational wave signals? Or out interference on the detectors from other (none GW sources, e.g. seismic activity).

Comment: Probably useful related questions: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235574/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/255317/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/382665/25301 and probably others

Comment: You might start with the principle of "linear superposition" (which is a rule about a very large class of waves including weak field gravitational waves).